# how to modify the color of fields of ls -la?

Tags: bash, zsh, ls, colors

I recently found an example of colored output when using ls:

[image]

AFAIK that is on MacOS with the BSD implementation of `ls`.

I know how I can change the color of the filenames via `LS_COLOR`, but I would like to color e.g. the permissions.

I could think of a combination of `sed`, ANSI escape codes and printing the output back to stdout, but that feels very heavy.

Has anyone an idea on how to accomplish that task with GNU `ls`?

Comment: Are you sure that your shell is `bash`?  (I know that a few years ago Mac switched to `zsh` as the default shell.)

Comment: @dg99 I use zsh on most systems, but I would prefer to find a solution which works for bash as well, as I use bash on a few of my machines.

Comment: The shell is irrelevant, this is all down to whatever program is listing the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do this with GNU `ls`, short of either post-processing the output (as you mention) or making the appropriate changes in the source code and building your own version.

The output you show looks like it came from [exa](https://the.exa.website/), not BSD `ls` (other than the colours, the absence of the group information suggests exa). You can install this on Linux too; that would probably be the simplest way of reproducing this type of output on your system.

Comment: It's also interesting that the screenshot shows an `l` command, not `ls`

Comment: Thanks, using exa is the more sane alternative to writing a wrapper script which adds the coloring. @JeffSchaller `l` would be an alias to `ls` + arguments if I recall correctly. I for example have the alias `l='ls -laht'` defined.